# How to calculating new vector in a direction from an existing vector

Tags: vectors

I’m writing a mod for a game called FiveM. I have a heading and an existing vector3 although I’ll just deal with non vertical so go with vector2. What I want is to calculate a new vector $(x_2,y_2)$ a known distance away from known vector $(x_1,y_1)$ along the known heading. Has been a looong time since I’ve looked at this stuff and I just need this one formula but don’t how how to derive it. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's just $$(x_2,y_2)=(x_1,y_1)+d~\frac{\mathrm{v}}{|\mathrm{v}|}$$

Answer (score 0):

What you need to find is a unit vector in the direction $(x_{1},y_{1})$. Which is precisely $\frac{1}{||(x_{1},y_{1})||}\cdot (x_{1},y_{1})$ , where $||(x_{1},y_{1})||$ denotes the norm of the vector with respect to whatever inner product is defined on the vector space. If you just have the usual standard inner product then $||(x_{1},y_{1})||=\sqrt{(x_{1})^{2}+(y_{1})^{2}}$.
Then you just take any parameter $t$ which is a scalor And the vector $(x_{2},y_{2})=(x_{1},y_{1})+\frac{t}{\sqrt{(x_{1})^{2}+(y_{1})^{2}}}(x_{1},y_{1})$ if it is just $\mathbb{R^{2}}$ you are concerned with. Now for different values of $t$ you will get different vectors which are in the same direction as $(x_{1},y_{1})$